# Selected item in RadioButton list to do page transfer

Tags: radiobuttonlist

I have a radio button list as the following:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RBjobSector" runat="server" style="font-size: medium">
    <asp:ListItem>apple</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>orange</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

How do I direct users to go either apple.aspx or orange.aspx page if users select either one of them after clicking the "Go" button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put below code to selectedIndex changed event

```
if (RBjobSector.SelectedIndex == 0)
   Reponse.Redirect("apple.aspx")


if (RBjobSector.SelectedIndex == 1)
   Reponse.Redirect("orange.aspx")
```